# HDMI disconnected in 18.04

Tags: hdmi

After upgrading to 18.04 HDMI output is no longer working. Seems as if HDMI is disconnected. How to make 18.04 connect and reestablish output through the HDMI connection on the computer.
Used to work in 16.04.

Comment: What video card do you have? Intel, Nvidia, AMD? Is the system a laptop or desktop? Does it still show the option in the Displays system settings? Do other outputs work like laptop screen or VGA? Does the system have multiple video cards (Intel integrated and Nvidia for example)

Comment: The video card is Intel® Ivybridge Mobile and it is in a laptop. result of xrandr: VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)