# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, hdmi monitor not recognized

Tags: nvidia, hdmi, acer, monitor

I was a bit unhappy about this situation as you may imagine.

I'm running Ubuntu in dual boot with windows, and I can work fine with the second monitor on Windows 10.

However, when I switch to Ubuntu, the monitor isn't recognized in the display menu (it just shows my regular laptop screen only). I think the hdmi cable should be connected and the monitor is powered itself.

The monitor is samsung syncmaster 226BW (an older monitor I reckon).

Laptop is acer nitro 5. Ubuntu is 18.04.2 LTS.

My laptop only has the hdmi port avaiable for monitors I think...

I apologize in advance I don't know how to properly format these terminal outputs into readable form in the ubuntu forums...
Here is some output from where I ran the `ubuntu-drivers devices` command

```
lauri@lauri-Nitro-AN515-51:~$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C8Dsv00001025sd0000118Bbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
driver   : nvidia-driver-418 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-415 - third-party free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

I've tried reinstalling drivers but that has not worked thus far to fix the problem.

Here below is the log-in screen, but the xorg thingy was unavailable in the "cog menu" near the sign in button, so I just chose regular Ubuntu. Those other choices seem to have been some kind of Ubuntu themes that I've been trying to install, but I'm not sure that those are very relevant to this issue.

[image]

Here below it shows I think what driver is being used, but nvidia x server settings also show blank screen for some reason which seems worrying...

[image]

I installed hwinfo and ran command "hwinfo --gfxcard", here is the output

```
lauri@lauri-Nitro-AN515-51:~$ hwinfo --gfxcard
15: PCI 100.0: 0300 VGA compatible controller (VGA)             
  [Created at pci.378]
  Unique ID: VCu0.utdygrXIfNE
  Parent ID: vSkL.JVzEGPFfAb1
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:01:00.0
  Hardware Class: graphics card
  Model: "nVidia GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]"
  Vendor: pci 0x10de "nVidia Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x1c8d "GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1025 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x118b 
  Revision: 0xa1
  Memory Range: 0xa3000000-0xa3ffffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0x90000000-0x9fffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xa0000000-0xa1ffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  I/O Ports: 0x4000-0x407f (rw,disabled)
  Memory Range: 0xa4080000-0xa40fffff (ro,non-prefetchable,disabled)
  IRQ: 255 (no events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v000010DEd00001C8Dsv00001025sd0000118Bbc03sc00i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: nvidiafb is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nvidiafb"
  Driver Info #1:
    Driver Status: nouveau is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nouveau"
  Driver Info #2:
    Driver Status: nvidia_drm is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nvidia_drm"
  Driver Info #3:
    Driver Status: nvidia is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nvidia"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #13 (PCI bridge)

23: PCI 02.0: 0300 VGA compatible controller (VGA)
  [Created at pci.378]
  Unique ID: _Znp.5o5btZi_3hC
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:02.0
  Hardware Class: graphics card
  Model: "Intel VGA compatible controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x591b 
  SubVendor: pci 0x1025 "Acer Incorporated [ALI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x118a 
  Revision: 0x04
  Memory Range: 0xa2000000-0xa2ffffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xb0000000-0xbfffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  I/O Ports: 0x5000-0x503f (rw)
  Memory Range: 0x000c0000-0x000dffff (rw,non-prefetchable,disabled)
  IRQ: 255 (no events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d0000591Bsv00001025sd0000118Abc03sc00i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: i915 is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe i915"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown

Primary display adapter: #15
```

Comment: hi, could you test the following to see if this fixes it : log out, the before you log back in again click on the little gear below your name and select xorg. it's possible that this is a 18.04 bug:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FtxL.jpg

Comment: Im sorry I didnt follow, do I do this in the log in screen already? (before having logged in?

Comment: uhm, you have to do this operation in the log in screen yes, you cannot do it while logged in. I expect that an xorg session will be able to detect your HDMI while a Wayland session (the default session type) will not.

Comment: Im currently on the ubuntu... I did not have those options of xorg available in the log-in cog menu. I have a picture but apparently cannot input the picture into the comments box

Comment: You cannot use the normal display settings menu with proprietary NVidia drivers. You have to use the proprietary NVidia tool to configure extra monitors. You are using the proprietary drivers (nvidia-driver-NNN) yes?

Comment: I will try to edit my own post for answers to the which drivers are in use, and the log-in screen for the earlier question... I will insert pictures also

Comment: @dobey not in my experience. I guess it depends on the monitor. but dual screen (one with Display port one with HDMI). Late347, to put pictures, you can use, imgur, like I did.