# HDMI port not showing up on xrandr - broken nvidia drivers?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, 18.04, nvidia, xrandr

I previously had everything working under ubuntu 16.04, but after installing regular updates and a reboot my HDMI port seems to have disappeared - running xrandr reports the following:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.06*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    40.04  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32
```

`lspci -v` reports:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company UHD Graphics 620
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 132
    Memory at b2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at b4320000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
    Memory at b4310000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at b4332000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 133
    Memory at b4333000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129
    Memory at b4330000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at b4336000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 5080 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 5088 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 5060 [size=32]
    Memory at b4334000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
    Memory behind bridge: b3000000-b3ffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000a0000000-00000000b1ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00006000-00006fff
    Memory behind bridge: b4200000-b42fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000090100000-00000000902fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: b4100000-b41fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00007000-00007fff
    Memory behind bridge: 90300000-904fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000090500000-00000000906fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d1b (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: b4000000-b40fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller/eSPI Controller - 9D4E (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 83f9
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP PMC
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at b432c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 135
    Memory at b4328000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at b4300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at b4335000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 5040 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 131
    Memory at b3000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at <ignored> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader
    Physical Slot: 4
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 128
    Memory at b4200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at b4104000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at b4100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

05:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2110
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 134
    Memory at b4000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Running `nvidia-settings` fails with the error "ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system", even though `sudo prime-select nvidia` indicates that the nvidia profile is already set.

I have tried reinstalling all the nvidia drivers and upgraded to ubuntu 18.04, with no success.

Comment: hi! this seems like a recuring thing for an update deliver to ubuntu 18.04 and under. would you mind testing under ubuntu 18.10? it seems the problem doesn't occur there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I was still somehow using the free drivers.

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
sudo apt install nvidia-390
```

and a reboot fixed my problem.