# Lubuntu 18.04 no video output

Tags: video, screen, xrandr, gpu-driver

I have problem with video output from my very old PC with Nvidia ION. I dont have video signal on monitor if I unplug DVI-HDMI cable from my monitor (HDMI) and do reboot and plug-it in again after boot.

I install TeamViewer on Lubuntu (works great) and I have video signal there every time without problem. If I keep DVI-HDMI cable plugged and do reboot, everything is OK and I see my desktop screen, but If I unplug before reboot - no image after I put HDMI back to my monitor

Can someone help me?

Comment: Try changing your display manager.

Comment: do you experience this bug under 18.10? under an xorg session? this seems to be a reccuring bug with ubuntu + 18.04 + Wayland + HDMI

Comment: tomorrow I will try fresh install ubuntu 18.04 and after that 18.10 and give you feedback...

Comment: 18.04 is doing the same like Lubuntu before, 18.10 after install after first reset will stuck on black screen - comming back to Windows :-(