# Ubuntu 18.04 Overscan/Underscan Issues

Tags: display-resolution

I am using an older flatscreen as a monitor. The issue is, it is an old enough TV that it does not have 1 to 1 pixel, or overscan/underscan options on any port except for the old VGA/PC Port, and I am connecting via HDMI from an AMD Radeon R9 290x. When I enable underscan in the settings, it makes it so the entire picture can be seen, but underscans it too much, causing the screen to be tiny, and also puts lines through the image, causing everything to look low quality, and for text to be hard to read. In addition, my TV is an old RCA L26WD26D, which supports a max resolution of 1368x768, which is also the resolution the TV manual recommends for PC connections (which Ubuntu for some reason wont let me set in the settings, without manually adding using xrandr).

So, I did the following in the terminal instead:

```
cvt 1366 768
    # 1368x768 59.88 Hz (CVT) hsync: 47.79 kHz; pclk: 85.25 MHz
    Modeline "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --newmode 1368x768_60.00 85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 1368x768_60.00
```

I then went into the settings and selected the new resolution. However, it was still overscanning, and turning on underscan in the settings presented the same issue as before, so I ran the following command:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --set underscan on
```

This fixed it underscanning too much, and the picture now matches the screen size exactly. However, it is still having issues with lines in the picture, making text hard to read, and all graphical elements and images look very bad. These are horizontal lines, not vertical, and I cannot find a way to make them go away, other than disabling underscanning, which makes the image too large for the screen again.

This is not an issue when I boot into Windows on the same machine, even though I am using underscanning to make the picture fit in Windows as well (however, underscanning is way more straight forward to get working right in Windows).

At this point, I would connect via VGA or DVI to get a resolution on this issue, but while my TV supports VGA, my graphics card does not, and my TV doesn't have a dedicated DVI input. I tried using a DVI to HDMI adapter on the TV, but the issue still persists. I have also tried using the amdgpu-pro drivers to see if they handle it any better than the open source drivers, but after installing, I get no image on boot, and I have to boot into recovery and issue the command "amdgpu-pro-uninstall" in the root terminal to get video working again, so that isn't an option. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello ! HDMI + ubuntu 18.04 + wayland is apparently a recipe for disaster. is displayport or usb-c an option. Or you can switch to ubuntu 18.10 or wait for the 18th of april for ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: My GPU does have a displayport output, but I have no displayport cables atm. Unfortunately, no USB-C option on this GPU, but I do have a type-c to HDMI connector for my cell phone, so if it did, I would have already tried that. I may have to go to 18.10. Only issue there is I usually don't like going to non LTS releases on my main machines, only on ones I use less frequently. I may do it anyways if it fixes the issue though.

Comment: okay, I understand. and btw converting a port to another is the same as that whole connection being of the end type. so usb-c to HDMI is still HDMI. I personally don't understand why Canonical had 18.04 labeled "LTS", I guess the timing just didn't work out in their favor but it has to be their most broken ubuntu release to date by a long margin. 18.10. I understand the apprehention at "leaving LTS grounds" that is why I mentioned waiting untill april 18th for 19.04 (yes it's not LTS either but it's not beta and it's going to be ubuntu's most stable release by far).

Comment: I understand that on converters. Either way, I am doing a dist upgrade to 18.10 now, as these aren't the only issues I have had with 18.04 (I get kernel panics at least a couple of times a day on 18.04 as well). Also, I am really glad I have an unlimited plan, cause I am downloading 18.10 using LTE data via wifi hotspot off my cell phone right now, lol.

Comment: see what I mean?.... (•ิ_•ิ)

Comment: Still having the same issue on 18.10 with the lines when underscanning is enabled.

Comment: ah jesus... sorry this hasen't yet fixed it. do you have radeon drivers installed yet? if not could you try? https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-amd-radeon-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux after that the only culprit I see is the HDMI. but I'm kind of low on ideas. you could also try upgrading the kernel with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa -y && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ukuu -y && sudo ukuu`

Comment: I have the drivers, but using underscan still has the same issue in Ubuntu. However, "xrandr --output HDMI-0 --scale 1.05x1.05" seems to have made everything small enough to fit on the screen without the issue with the lines, but I now need to re-alight the top left portion of the screen as scale does not do that automatically. Issue is I am having trouble remembering the syntax for that command. I know it is an xrandr command, but I can't remember it exactly.

Comment: hold on is xandr re-aligning automatically or not re-aligning automatically? does this help : https://superuser.com/a/485165/350509

Comment: with scale, xrandr does not re-align automatically, unlike with transform or underscan. It just scales everything down so it will fit. It is then up to you to align the top left corner so it does.

Comment: so `--pos 0x0?` single screen right?

Comment: --pos 0x0 doesn't move it at all, yes single screen.

Comment: what dirrection is it off i and about how much is it off by, you could try different values? or is --pos not at all what we are looking for? could you provide a photo of what you are seeing?

Comment: --pos seems to only adjust it in relation to other monitors, so it wouldn't be it. it is about 20 pixels too far up, and 20 pixels too far to the left, so it needs to be adjusted 20x20 pixels down and to the right.

Comment: and you can't do this in the Radeon GUI settings?

Comment: You only get the Radeon GUI settings when the amdgpu-pro proprietary drivers are installed, and those appear to have a system crashing bug at the moment. But I know the Windows version has the feature built into it. I'm sure if I could get them working, the Linux proprietary drivers probably would too, but all I get when they are installed is a black screen.